# Graphviz for documenting EVMS chart

Tags: charts, visualization, graphviz, diagram, dot

I am evaluating ways to generate charts similar to the following. Would graphviz with subplots be an appropriate approach, or is there a better way? Not even sure what to look for in a web search right now.

Would like to show a WBS in tree form across the top, an Organizational Structure in tree form on the left side and then, where appropriate, control account designations in the cells that correspond to intersecting leaf nodes.

[image: EVMS Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the automatic layouts in the GraphViz package can help you here, alone. While at the top and at the right side the graph does look like a regular tree structure which should be easily doable with the "dot" hierarchical style, the difficult part would be to get the matrix style in the center of the graph or more specifically merging the two tree layouts in the matrix.

Even with a more sophisticated diagramming and layout library, this kind of layout would require some manual configuration and extra coding (which nodes belong to the top and right hand side, which ones belong to the "matrix" part, etc.).

If you try [yFiles](https://yworks.com/yfiles), you would need to combine two instances of the TreeLayout, one GenericPartitionGridStage combined with a LayoutMultiplexer, one TabularLayout and a StraightLineRouter or use a custom "LayoutStage" for the simple "matrix part". Doable and feasible, but certainly not a simple task.

<sup>Full disclosure: I work for the company that creates the above mentioned graph layout library. I do not represent my employer here on SO, though. Thoughts and comments are my own.</sup>